# AngularJs- Cannot click buttons inside dialog(Dialog disabled when it open)

Tags: angularjs, ng-dialog

I used ngDialog, angularJs plugin from : http://ngmodules.org/modules/ngDialog
when the openDialog button is clicked the dialog opens but it is disabled. I am unable interact with the dialog.

HTML file:

```
<body ng-app="managePartners">
<div ng-controller="managePartnerController">
<button ng-click="openTheDialog()">Open Dialog</button>
</div>
</body>
```

myScript.js file:

```
    var app = angular.module("managePartners",['ngDialog']);
    app.controller("managePartnerController", function($scope , ngDialog){

      $scope.openTheDialog = function(){

      var dialog = ngDialog.open({
                template: '<p>Are you sure you want to close the parent dialog?</p>' +
                                '<div class="ngdialog-buttons">' +
                                    '<button type="button" class="ngdialog-button ngdialog-button-secondary" ng-click="closeThisDialog(0)">No' +
                                    '<button type="button" class="ngdialog-button ngdialog-button-primary" ng-click="confirm(1)">Yes' +
                                '</button></div>',
                plain: true,
                closeByDocument: false,
                closeByEscape: true,
                showClose:false,
                scope:$scope,

            });

  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Importing all the Css file of the plugin made it work!